# How to find the $x$ in this equation with permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find "$x$" if:
a)$$10*^{x}P_2=^{x+1}P_4$$ 
b)$$3*^{2x+4}P_3=2*^{x+41}P_4$$

That is all the information they gave me for this problem. I'm learning about combinations and permutations.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to a guy who posted earlier
a) $$10*^{x}P_2=^{x+1}P_4$$ 
$$10*(x)(x-1)=(x+1)(x)(x-1)(x-2)$$ 
$$10=(x+1)(x-2)$$ 
$$10=x^2-x-2$$ 
$$0=x^2-x-12$$ 
$$(x-4)(x+3)$$

The problem b) is the same

Comment: Since $P(n, k) = 0$ if $k > n$, only one of those solutions is valid.